# npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! Aborting installation. npm install --no-audit --save --save-e

Tags: reactjs

PS E:\React> npx create-react-app task

Creating a new React app in E:\React\task.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\santo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-15T06_08_33_703Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting task/ from E:\React

i'm gettibg this msg can anyone help me

Comment: Your error message says it: “ This is a problem related to network connectivity.” Not really much we could help with except for asking you to check your network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with better connectivity. Because npx fetch data from server which required network connection Once you successfully generate project you can  work without network connection.